# Multiple Ruby apps on one port, RackBaseURI help

Tags: ruby, passenger

I'm trying to get two Ruby apps to work from the same port.  I don't know server technology at all, so forgive my ignorance.  I've tried to follow this doc:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

sections 4.1 - 4.3, but I keep messing something up.  I've tried to simplify a little, so here is my situation.  I have two simple rackup apps here:

/Users/dan/webapps/test1
/Users/dan/webapps/test2

They each have the "config.ru" file, the public/ folder, and the tmp/ folder with "restart.txt", as directed. They both work on their own.

I have the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /Users/dan/webapps
  <Directory /Users/dan/webapps>
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  RackBaseURI /test1
  <Directory /Users/dan/webapps/test1>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  RackBaseURI /test2
  <Directory /Users/dan/webapps/test2>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I start apache, and then put this in my browser: http://localhost/test1. I get:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test1 on this server.

I'm not surprised it doesn't work, because I am supposed to set up a symlink but I don't know how to apply that to my setup.  Here is the example from the doc:

ln -s /webapps/rackapp/public /websites/phusion/rack

Can you tell me how to set up the symlinks, and let me know if you see anything else wrong?  Please give the "for dummies" answer, this stuff boggles my mind.  Thanks!

Comment: Is your apache server able to read from these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phylae, I think you may have the paths reversed in the symbolic link.  To get it working, I changed the link names for clarity:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /Users/dan/webapps
  <Directory /Users/dan/webapps>
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  RackBaseURI /test1link
  <Directory /Users/dan/webapps/test1>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  RackBaseURI /test2link
  <Directory /Users/dan/webapps/test2>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and then, the symbolic links:

ln -s /Users/dan/webapps/test1/public /Users/dan/webapps/test1link

ln -s /Users/dan/webapps/test2/public /Users/dan/webapps/test2link

Then these urls work as expected in a browser.

http://localhost/

http://localhost/test1link

http://localhost/test2link

Answer (score 0):

To create the symlinks, try this:

```
ln-s /Users/dan/webapps/test1 /Users/dan/webapps/test1/public
ln-s /Users/dan/webapps/test2 /Users/dan/webapps/test2/public
```

However, as chris polzer mentioned, you should also check that your apache user can read from those directories.

If you don't know how to do that, then post the output of these commands:

```
ls -l /Users/dan/webapps/test1
ls -l /Users/dan/webapps/test2.
ps -aux | grep http
ps -aux | grep apache
```

You may also need to check the permissions of all parent directories. I.e. /Users, /Users/dan, and /Users/dan/webapps. See: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2